# SWT KeyUp event listener misses keys

Tags: java, swt, keylistener

I have the following code:

```
display.addFilter(SWT.KeyUp, new Listener()
{
    public void handleEvent(Event e)
    {
        System.out.println("Released " + e.character);
    }
};
```

When I press down the keys 'a', 's', 'd', and 'f' at the same time, the KeyDown event works as expected. However, when I release all of the keys at the same time I expect the output to be something like:

Released a
Released s
Released d
Released f

But this is not the case. What is printed out is usually just one character, such as:

Released d

Why is it skipping out on the other two or three events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=50020).

> **Bug 50020 - KeyReleased not working correctly**. 
>   KeyReleased seems to be firing incorrectly or not at all in the following case:
>   Several keys are pressed, in succession, and held down. One by one, the keys 
>   are released. The keyReleased event fires but the event.character is always the 
>   last key that was pressed. If the last key that was pressed is released, all 
>   the other keys do not fire a released event when they are released.

The bug probably never get fixed (Comment #1 in the bugtracker entry):

> **Comment #1**
>
>   This is a very old bug that we probably won't fix.  The problem is
>   that there  is not enough information in Window to compute the key
>   that was pressed in  WM_KEYUP.